# Compare two deeply nested arrays in javascript using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have two arrays as follows:

```
const initBlocks = [
    {
        closingDays: [
            {start: '01/10/2020', stop: '10/10/2020', type: 'workplace', reference: '', uuid: ''}
        ],
        openingsHours: [
            { start: '07:00', stop: '12:30', type: 'workplace', day: 'mon', reference: '', uuid: ''}
            { start: '07:00', stop: '12:30', type: 'workplace', day: 'tue', reference: '', uuid: ''}
        ],
        order: 0,
        reference: "123"
    }
    {
        openingsHours: [
            {start: '07:00', stop: '12:30', type: 'workplace', day: 'mon', reference: '', uuid: ''}
        ],
        order: 0,
        reference: "123"
    }
]
```

And the second one:

```
 const blocks = [
    {
        closingDays: [
            {start: '01/10/2020', stop: '10/10/2020', type: 'workplace', reference: '', uuid: ''}
        ],
        openingsHours: [
            { start: '07:00', stop: '12:30', type: 'workplace', day: 'mon', reference: '', uuid: ''}
            { start: '07:00', stop: '12:30', type: 'showroom', day: 'tue', reference: '', uuid: ''}
        ],
        order: 0,
        reference: "123"
    }
    {
        openingsHours: [
            {start: '07:00', stop: '12:30', type: 'workplace', day: 'mon', reference: '', uuid: ''}
            {start: '07:00', stop: '12:30', type: 'workplace', day: 'mon', reference: '', uuid: ''}
        ],
        order: 1,
        reference: "321"
    }
]
```

I want to compare those two and I want to see if `openingsHours` are the same. It can be more objects in the array, then the properties (start, stop, type and day) can be different.

I've tried something as follows:

```
let areEqual = true;
filter(blocks, block => {
    return filter(initBlocks, initBlock => {
        const blockHours = block.openingsHours.map(item => { return { ...omit(item, ['reference', 'uuid']) } })
        const initBlockHours = initBlock.openingsHours.map(item => { return { ...omit(item, ['reference', 'uuid']) } })
        if(!isEqual(blockHours, initBlockHours)){
            areEqual = false
        }
    })
})
```

But the result in `areEqual` is not what it should be. They are not the same thus it should be `false`, but I'm getting `true`. Any idea?

Comment: When you say "it's not as it should be", what exactly is the problem? Is there an error? Is the returned data incorrect? Please share the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: @EvanBechtol The variable `areEqual` should be `false` because they are not the same, but I get `true`.

Comment: Are you getting an error, what's the exact issue?

Comment: @EvanBechtol Before filtering. `isEqual` is from lodash. And I'm not getting error, the filtering is not correct, because I get that they are the same but the arent.

Comment: It would be useful to know what your expected output should look like.

Comment: You should probably initialize `areEqual` to false and only set it to true if the two objects are actually equal (by whatever logic you have for equality).

Comment: @EvanBechtol It should be true or false, nothing else. Thus, if `blocks` and ìnitBlocks` are exactly the same it should return true and otherwise false.

Comment: @jarmod I do the same thing, just inversely. I set it to true and then to false if they are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you should start out with `areEqual` set to `false`. Then, we only change it if there are values that are equal, and if they are equal, we immediately return.

```
const { filter, isEqual, omit } = require( "lodash" );
const initBlocks = [
  {
    closingDays: [
      {
        start: "01/10/2020",
        stop: "10/10/2020",
        type: "workplace",
        reference: "",
        uuid: ""
      }
    ],
    openingsHours: [
      {
        start: "07:00",
        stop: "12:30",
        type: "workplace",
        day: "mon",
        reference: "",
        uuid: ""
      },
      {
        start: "07:00",
        stop: "12:30",
        type: "workplace",
        day: "tue",
        reference: "",
        uuid: ""
      }
    ],
    order: 0,
    reference: "123"
  },
  {
    openingsHours: [
      {
        start: "07:00",
        stop: "12:30",
        type: "workplace",
        day: "mon",
        reference: "",
        uuid: ""
      }
    ],
    order: 0,
    reference: "123"
  }
];
const blocks = [
  {
    closingDays: [
      {
        start: "01/10/2020",
        stop: "10/10/2020",
        type: "workplace",
        reference: "",
        uuid: ""
      }
    ],
    openingsHours: [
      {
        start: "07:00",
        stop: "12:30",
        type: "workplace",
        day: "mon",
        reference: "",
        uuid: ""
      },
      {
        start: "07:00",
        stop: "12:30",
        type: "showroom",
        day: "tue",
        reference: "",
        uuid: ""
      }
    ],
    order: 0,
    reference: "123"
  },
  {
    openingsHours: [
      {
        start: "07:00",
        stop: "12:30",
        type: "workplace",
        day: "mon",
        reference: "",
        uuid: ""
      },
      {
        start: "07:00",
        stop: "12:30",
        type: "workplace",
        day: "mon",
        reference: "",
        uuid: ""
      }
    ],
    order: 1,
    reference: "321"
  }
];

let areEqual = false;

filter( blocks, block => {
  return filter( initBlocks, initBlock => {
    const blockHours = block.openingsHours.map( item => {
      return { ...omit( item, [ "reference", "uuid" ] ) };
    } );

    const initBlockHours = initBlock.openingsHours.map( item => {
      return { ...omit( item, [ "reference", "uuid" ] ) };
    } );
    
    if ( isEqual( blockHours, initBlockHours ) ) {
      areEqual = true;
      return;
    }
  } );
} );

console.log(areEqual);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the order inside the arrays does matter in the comparison you should do this:

```
const check = initBlocks
  .map((b, idx) => {
    const _bOpeningHours = [...b.openingsHours];
    delete _bOpeningHours.reference;
    delete _bOpeningHours.uuid;
    const _blocksOpeningHours = [...blocks[idx].openingsHours];
    delete _blocksOpeningHours.reference;
    delete _blocksOpeningHours.uuid;
    return lodash.isEqual(_bOpeningHours, _blocksOpeningHours);
  })
  .every((c) => !!c);
```

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-torvalds-ttisu)

If the order shouldn't matter you should group the opening hours of the two arrays in one array for each array you compare, then sort them and use isEqual to get the result:

```
const _initBlocks = initBlocks.map(b => b.openingHours).sort()
const _blocks = blocks.map(b => b.openingHours).sort()

const result = lodash.isEqual(_initBlocks, _blocks);
```

Note: Do not use sort() as it is, because the openingHours contain Objets. Use a custom sort() function to sort them based on a value you want. Otherwise the isEqual() will take into account the order of the elements. Same goes for the objects inside the openingHours, you should sort them as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking on all inner objects, you can try to eliminate duplicates and use a custom format with necessary value.

For comparison, I'm using following format:

```
{
  "workplace|mon": "07:00|12:30",
  "workplace|tue": "07:00|12:30"
}
```

Once you have processed to get necessary values, you can just check the equality using lodash's `isEqual` and return it

```js
function getTypeBasedHours(array) {
  return array.reduce((acc, item) => {
    item.openingsHours.forEach((workDetails) => {
      const key = `${workDetails.type}|${workDetails.day}`;
      acc[key] = `${workDetails.start}|${workDetails.stop}`
    })
    return acc
  }, {})
}

const initBlocks=[{closingDays:[{start:"01/10/2020",stop:"10/10/2020",type:"workplace",reference:"",uuid:""}],openingsHours:[{start:"07:00",stop:"12:30",type:"workplace",day:"mon",reference:"",uuid:""},{start:"07:00",stop:"12:30",type:"workplace",day:"tue",reference:"",uuid:""}],order:0,reference:"123"},{openingsHours:[{start:"07:00",stop:"12:30",type:"workplace",day:"mon",reference:"",uuid:""}],order:0,reference:"123"}];
const blocks=[{closingDays:[{start:"01/10/2020",stop:"10/10/2020",type:"workplace",reference:"",uuid:""}],openingsHours:[{start:"07:00",stop:"12:30",type:"workplace",day:"mon",reference:"",uuid:""},{start:"07:00",stop:"12:30",type:"showroom",day:"tue",reference:"",uuid:""}],order:0,reference:"123"},{openingsHours:[{start:"07:00",stop:"12:30",type:"workplace",day:"mon",reference:"",uuid:""},{start:"07:00",stop:"12:30",type:"workplace",day:"mon",reference:"",uuid:""}],order:1,reference:"321"}];

const map1 = getTypeBasedHours(initBlocks)
const map2 = getTypeBasedHours(blocks)

console.log(map1, map2)

console.log(_.isEqual(map1, map2))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```